# Bash Scripting; alias command inside a x.sh script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple script using bash which must take two variables: a name and a command; then apply these two variables inside a "alias" command like so: alias $1=$2.

It`s for an online school activity which teaches introduction to bash scripting.

What I have come up with is:

```
function doalias {
alias $1=$2
}

doalias $1 $2
```

Next thing I do is write inside the terminal ./doalias.sh inst "sudo apt-get install".

Now the message I get from the bash terminal is that "=" is not recognized as a command. Why is this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the passed parameter in quotes when actioning the alias command and so:

```
function doalias {
  alias "$1=$2"
}

doalias "$1" "$2"
```

To have the alias set in the current shell, you will need to source the script and so:

```
source doalias.sh inst "sudo apt-get install"
```

Comment: Hi. So i did this and i stoped getting the "= in not a command" line but now instead when i go ahead and check if the alias aplied by calling it with inst the line i get is that that command is not found. Maybe if you apply an alias via a script it actually wont apply at all?

Comment: Yeah, the alias will only be relevant to the running shell. To make it active in the current shell, you will need to source the script

Comment: It might be out of the object of the question but how could i source the script?

Comment: I've just added it to the question. ./ runs the command in a new shell. Source runs the script in the current shell

Comment: Thanks. That made it.